# Method for calculating quality of object tracking

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm looking for a method to calculate the tracking quality in real-time. I currently use the most known method for tracking: Correlation Filter, KCF and CSRT. I want a value the indicate my tracking quality indipendently to the method used.

My test dataset has no bounding-box so I can't calculate the overlap between groundtrouth and prediction.
The only method I have found in the state of the art is PSR (Peak-to-sidelobe-ratio).

Does OpenCV support this functionality? Does anyone know a method for calculating the quality?

Comment: What about annotating the bounding boxes?

Comment: In real-time application I need this index...i haven't bounding box

Comment: PSR is for detectors that _have_ a spatial response and a peak in that, and you'd need to say where the "side lobe" starts (what radius around the peak). it's not universally applicable. it's also not exactly "state of the art", I'd say. -- consult the papers that presented those algorithms. -- you can generally not trust *algorithms* to know the truth, or to assess their own "confusion". ground truth comes from strong intelligence. the only known implementation of that is humans.

Comment: @Daniele Mugnai: what about recording your tracking results + images and manually annotate correctness?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I know that PSR is not state of the art but is the only metrics that I have found to indicate in some way the "quality" of tracker. I'm looking a method to evaluate how the response is good in tracking. Considering the peak and neighbour is a possibile solution but I would like to evaluate something else.

Comment: @Micka Consider a rea-time solution, how you indicate the tracker quality?

Comment: in any case, you'd need to somehow reach into these implementations and get a hold of their internal runtime state. I don't think the opencv tracking interface reveals much beyond bounding boxes.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, yes i know. I'm using the implementation of KCF filter not the one proposed from OpenCV.